# Xamarin huge load while recreating ContentPage

Tags: c#, class, xamarin, instance

To make my code look a little bit better i made a class for every Page i'm creating. But in that page i create another instance of that page to load again. The first few times it worked well but then the app started struggling while using the Images and layouts.
i did NOT load the image everytime again, the main images are global variables so there shouldn't be any huge laggs.

my **C# class** code on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/n3WVGNTb

i also get some messages in my output, i copied some here:

```
01-06 16:11:57.253 I/art     (28194): Starting a blocking GC Explicit
01-06 16:11:57.267 I/art     (28194): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1191(30KB) AllocSpace objects, 23(748KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 16MB/27MB, paused 190us total 13.348ms
01-06 16:11:57.268 D/Mono    (28194): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 83 objects 477 opaque 11 colors 83 colors-bridged 83 colors-visible 83 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.09ms tarjan 0.20ms scc-setup 0.06ms gather-xref 0.00ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.05ms
01-06 16:11:57.268 D/Mono    (28194): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 15.13ms
01-06 16:11:57.268 D/Mono    (28194): GC_MAJOR: (LOS overflow) time 19.71ms, stw 20.25ms los size: 6144K in use: 791K
01-06 16:11:57.268 D/Mono    (28194): GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 7040K in use: 5694K
01-06 16:11:57.365 D/Mono    (28194): GC_BRIDGE waiting for bridge processing to finish
01-06 16:11:57.367 I/art     (28194): Starting a blocking GC Explicit
01-06 16:11:57.367 D/Mono    (28194): GC_BRIDGE waiting for bridge processing to finish
01-06 16:11:57.381 I/art     (28194): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1173(29KB) AllocSpace objects, 18(504KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 16MB/28MB, paused 191us total 13.372ms
01-06 16:11:57.382 D/Mono    (28194): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 82 objects 475 opaque 10 colors 82 colors-bridged 82 colors-visible 82 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.08ms tarjan 0.20ms scc-setup 0.06ms gather-xref 0.00ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.05ms
01-06 16:11:57.382 D/Mono    (28194): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 15.36ms
01-06 16:11:57.382 D/Mono    (28194): GC_MAJOR: (LOS overflow) time 19.03ms, stw 20.61ms los size: 6144K in use: 791K
01-06 16:11:57.382 D/Mono    (28194): GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 6992K in use: 5666K
```

---

Since nobody has an idea i'll skip that problem. i might try to split the constructor so that no code is unneccessarily double called 
One thing i noticed: it just happens in the "Zeichnen" mode. Which has a SkiaSharp Finger Drawing interface, 2 more icons than usual but that should be all that differs.

Comment: I think nobody look through your 300 LOC. For this problems are debuggers built. Record the session and then check the memory to know what isn't finalized by the GC.

Comment: i don't even know what a GC is... and i don't even know in detail what a debugger is XD what i know is: the app is built when i click the play button.

Comment: and i might add: i added my c# source code in pastebin. not the output of my.. whatever it's called^^

Comment: Well, then I don't think you should handle with advanced stuff at all. A basic knowledge of the GC and debugger should be there. For debugging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio?tabs=csharp
For GC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/

Comment: well since it has to have something to do with my code i hoped you guys could take a broad look into it and maybe you notice something i am doing wrong.

Comment: and... i know how to set a breakpoint. that's the most basic thing a programmer should know XD but since it slows down more and more every time i create a new instance of my ContentView class i don't think it's a short sight problem but more on the long sight.
you know like some memory overflow or some of those things i just don't see and know about